# Using NSUrlConnection inside either NSThread or NSOperation

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsthread, nsoperation, synchronous

I am developing a static library that needs to do some stuff in the background, without interacting with the main thread. To give you an idea, think of just logging some user events. The library must keep doing this stuff until the user exits the app or sends it to the background (pushes the home button) - in other words it needs to keep doing stuff inside a loop.

The only interaction between the main app thread and the spawned thread is that occasionally the main app thread will put some stuff (an event object) into a queue that the spawned thread can read/consume. Other than that, the spawned thread just keeps going until the app exists or backgrounds.

Part of what the spawned thread needs to do (though not all of it) involves sending data to an HTTP server. I would have thought that it would be easy to subclass NSThread, override its main method, and just make a synchronous call to NSUrlConnection with some sort of timeout on that connection so the thread doesn't hang forever. For example, in Java/Android, we just subclass Thread, override the start() method and call a synchronous HTTP GET method (say from Apache's HttpClient class). This is very easy and works fine. But from what I have seen here and elsewhere, apparently on iOS it is much more complicated than this and I'm more than a bit confused as to what the best approach is that actually works.

So should I subclass NSThread and somehow use NSUrlConnection? It seems the asynchronous NSUrlConnection does not work inside NSThread because delegate methods don't get called but what about the synchronous method? Do I somehow need to use and configure the RunLoop and set up an autorelease pool? Or should I use an NSOperation? It seems to me that what I am trying to do is pretty common - does anyone have a working example of how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, to use `NSURLConnection` asynchronously you need a runloop.  Even if you use an `NSOperation` you still need a runloop.

All the examples I have seen use the `Main Thread` to start `NSURLConnection` which has a runloop.  The examples using `NSOperation` are set up so the operation is `Concurrent` which tells `NSOperationQueue` not to provide it's own thread, they then make sure that `NSURLConnection` is started on the main thread, for example via a call to `performSelectorOnMainThread:`

Here is an example:

[Pulse Engineering Blog: Concurrent Downloads using NSOperationQueues](http://eng.pulse.me/concurrent-downloads-using-nsoperationqueues/)

You can also search the Apple documentation for `QRunLoopOperation` in the `LinkedImageFetcher` sample which is an example class showing some ins and outs of this kind of thing.

*(Although I'm not sure I actually saw any code that example showing how to run your own runloop, again this example relies on the main thread.)*

Answer (score 0):

I've used the grand central dispatch (GCD) methods to achieve this. Here is an example that worked for me in a simple test app (I'm not sure if it applies in a static library, but may be worth a look). I'm using ARC.

In the example, I am kicking off some background work from my viewDidLoad method, but you can kick it off from anywhere. The key is that "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue…" runs the block in a background thread. See this answer for a good explanation of that method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12693409/215821

Here is my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, (unsigned long)NULL), 
        ^(void) {
            [self doStuffInBackground];
        });
}
```

The doStuffInBackground method is running in the background at this point, so you can just use NSURLConnection synchronously. In my example here, the method loops making network calls until presumably some other code sets backgroundStuffShouldRun = false. A network call is made with a 10 second timeout. After the call, I'm updating a UI label just to show progress. Note that the UI update is performed with "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()…". This runs the UI update on the UI thread, as required.

One potential issue with this background work: there isn't a way to cancel the http request itself. But, with a 10 second timeout, you'd be waiting a max of 10 seconds for the thread to abort itself after an outsider (likely some event in your UI) sets backgroundStuffShouldRun = false.

```
- (void)doStuffInBackground
{
    while (backgroundStuffShouldRun) {
        // prepare for network call...
        NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo"];

        // set a 10 second timeout on the request
        NSURLRequest* request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:10];

        NSError* error = nil;
        NSURLResponse *response = nil;

        // make the request
        NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        // were we asked to stop the background processing?
        if (!backgroundStuffShouldRun) {
            return;
        }

        // process response...

        NSString* status = @"Success";

        if (error) {
            if (error.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut) {
                // handle timeout...
                status = @"Timed out";
            }
            else {
                // handle other errors...
                status = @"Other error";
            }
        }
        else {
            // success, handle the response body
            NSString *dataAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"%@", dataAsString);
        }


        // update the UI with our status
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [statusLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"completed network call %d, status = %@", callCount, status]];
        });

        callCount++;
        sleep(1); // 1 second breather. not necessary, but good idea for testing
    }

}
```